# List ONE level subfolder content on external hard disc (PC batch)

Tags: batch-file, directory, command-prompt, subdirectory

I'm an enthusiast photographer.
In my PC (windows 7) I would like to let a batch file list my external hard disc content to a file (dir names only, not file names).
But I like to list the root folders and ONLY ONE LEVEL subfolders, preferably in a format like one folder and its subfolders, then the next folder and its subfolders etc.
Thanks

Comment: An example of what you really want will be helpfull...

Comment: not sure, what you want. Maybe `tree d:` or `tree d:\` does something what you like. Replace `d:` with your correct drive-letter. To get the output into a file, type `tree d: >myfile.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
    set "drive=d:"
    for /d %%r in ("%drive%\*") do (
        echo %%~fr
        for /d %%f in ("%%r\*") do echo(       %%~nxf
        echo(
    )
```

For each folder in the root of the drive, show the name of the folder and for each folder inside it, show its name

Comment: yeah that's better. @user3074464 put a >> file.txt at end of last paren for output and set "drive=e:"

Comment: Thank you @MC ND a lot! This made the thing! Also thanks @joojaa!

Comment: you should accept and upvote instead of saying thanx that's the way the site works.

Comment: Not sure how to do that? MC ND's answer I used, and did I manage to vote that? When trying to vote @joojaa it says "I need 15 reputations"?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
setlocal
set basedir=p:\

FOR /f %%g IN ('dir /B /AD %basedir%') do call :doOneFolder %%g

:doOneFolder foldername
  echo %1
  FOR /f %%g IN ('dir /B /AD %basedir%%1') do echo     %%g
```

change the basedir to something you need

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately my programming knowledge didn't let me finalize this. So: I have the harddisc on E:, and lets say that the batch is under C:, and finally that I want to write a txt-file under c: where the E-folder content is listed.